# log4j appender config

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, tomcat5.5, rollingfileappender

Is there a way to run log4j appender at a specified time?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I have put the `log4j.properties` under `/opt/tomcat0/common/classes`

Comment: You don't "run" appenders. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Kaushal probably means "rolling" the log file at specified hour, not at the start fo each * (hour/minute/day). For example how do I roll 4 times a day, each 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to enable / disable logging at runtime ?

If the above assumption is right - you can do the same via JMX.

Comment: Basically if i set log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd in
log4j.properties It rolls over at midnight. is there a way to roll
over at say 12:00 Noon

Please suggest/guide

Thanks,

Kaushal